# Dynamic background image not working - Angular 5

Tags: css, angular

I am setting background image with ngStyle, like this:

```
<section [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + backgroundUrl + ') no-repeat 0 0 / cover'}" class="slider flex-center">
```

In .ts file:

```
this.backgroundUrl = this.homeModelResponse.featuredStories[0].fullHDUrl;
```

The problem is, if user uploads the same images, i get url like this:

```
https://..something/264/2970/7745/9960/rawpixel-com-256641_(1)_org_hd_ready.jpg.jpg
```

with *(1)* in brackets, and my guess is that css doesn't work good with that, all other images are displayed but just the copies with this type of path are not.

It works with `img` tag but doesn't with background property in css.

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Background image does not allow (), space, single quotes and double quotes in the image path.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height` and `width` of `section` tag.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-background-image-not-working-angular-5?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<section style="height:300px;width:300px;" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + backgroundUrl + ') no-repeat 0 0 / cover'}" class="slider flex-center">
```